# Criteria eager fetch-joined collection to avoid n+1 selects

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Let's say Item and Bid are entities: an Item has many Bids. They are mapped in **Hibernate** in a  typical parent/child relationship:

```xml
<class name="Item" table="ITEM">
  ...
  <set name="bids" inverse="true">
    <key column="ITEM_ID"/>
    <one-to-many class="Bid"/>
  </set>
</class>
```

How can I avoid n+1 selects when trying to access the bids of each Item after this query is executed?

```java
List<Item> items = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
                        .createAlias("bids", "b").
                        .add(Restrictions.gt("b.amount", 100)).
                        .list();
```

**Note** I need an *eager fetching* for bids but ***with a further restriction on the collection*** (b.amount > 100)

I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

```java
List<Item> items = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
                        .setFetchMode("bids", FetchMode.JOIN).
                        .createAlias("bids", "b").
                        .add(Restrictions.gt("b.amount", 100)).
                        .list();                        

List<Item> items = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
                        .createCriteria("bids")
                        .add(Restrictions.gt("amount", 100)).
                        .list();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617145/hibernate-fetching-strategy-when-to-use-join-and-when-to-use-select
I think it is being asked before....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an explanation of why adding a restriction on the fetch-joined collection causes the collection was not initialized (**note** that the same query without the restriction produce an eager fetch for the collection):

> "If you have a 1:n relation between tables A and B, and you add a restriction to B and want to fetch A and B it eagerly, the question would be what happens when you want to navigate from A to B.
>   Should you only see the data in B that matches the restriction, or should you see all Bs that are related to A?" [see more here ...](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=944439&sid=7f975b6c31faab79ed28dee887f6606e)

However, using HQL instead of criteria, fetch partially the bids collections

```java
List<Item> items = session.createQuery(
          "from Item i left join fetch i.bids b where b.amount > :amount")
          .setParameter("amount", 100)
          .list();
```

*It seems to me an inconsistency, but it's how this works*

By the way, if what you need is the list of parents and all its children, but just the parents whose children all meet certain restriction, so you may use this

```java
List<Item> items = session.createQuery(
          "from Item i left join fetch i.bids b " +
          "where not exists (from Bid b where b.item = i and b.amount <= :amount)")
          .setParameter("amount", 100)
          .list();
```

This is a related posts: [Hibernate query not returning full object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147769/hibernate-query-not-returning-full-object?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 11):

This criteria query seems right:

```
  List<Item> items = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
                    .setFetchMode("bids", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .createAlias("bids", "b")
                    .add(Restrictions.gt("b.amount", 100))
                    .list();
```

`FetchMode.JOIN` is meant to solve `n+1` problem. Have you defined some  `default_batch_fetch_size` |  `batch-size` anywhere in the mapping or configuration, which is reverse impacting?

If not, can you please try below HQL and see this solves your problem?

```
 Query query = 
      session.createQuery("from Item it left join it.bids b where b.amount=:bids");
 query.setParamter(bids, 100);
 List<Item> items = query.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a Criteria that uses Subquery Exists on another Criteria. A similar answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15768089/1469525

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Item.class, "i");
criteria.setFetchMode("bids", FetchMode.JOIN);

DetachedCriteria bidCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Bid.class, "b");
bidCriteria.add(Restrictions.gt("amount", 100));
bidCriteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("b.itemId", "i.id"));
criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(bidCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("b.id"))));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. Its solved my problem.

```
List<Item> items = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
                .setFetchMode("bids", FetchMode.SELECT)
                .createAlias("bids", "b")
                .add(Restrictions.gt("b.amount", 100))
                .list();
```